# Example 2, Sec. 25, in Munkres TOPOLOGY 2nd ed: Is this subspace also connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

The topologist's sine curve is the closure $\overline{S}$ of the subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, where
$$S\  = \ \left\{ \ x \times \sin \frac{1}{x} \ \colon \ 0 < x \leq 1 \ \right\}.$$
So
$$\overline{S} = S \cup V,$$
where
$$V = \{0 \} \times [-1,1].$$

Now let $A$ be the subset of  $V$ obtained by removing all points with rational second co-ordinates; that is let
$$A = \{0\} \times \big( [-1,1] - \mathbb{Q} \big). $$

Then $A$ is not connected as a subspace of $V$.

Am I right?

Is $A$ connected as a subsapce of  $\overline{S}$?

Comment: Regarding question 2: It looks like $A$ is not a subspace of $S$ at all; am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @EricStucky, you're absolutely right. I'll edit my post forthwith.

Comment: I've made a correction to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is connected, and consider the inclusion mappings $A \to V \to \Bbb{R^2}$. These maps are continuous, so you conclude that $A$ is connected also as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Contradiction.

Comment: $A$ is not connected in $V$. Can't we use the same argument with $V$ replaced by $\overline{S}$ to conclude that $A$ is not connected in $\overline{S}$?

Comment: Yes. Crostul's answer is actually exactly the same as that, but with a fancy wrapper around it.

Comment: Oh, yes, this argument applies on every set containing $A$.